# AutoCompleteExtender in 3tier Architecture

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services

i am using AutoCompleteExtender in my project.and i declared the webserive in BL LAYER.And exposing it to my project.but i dont know what to give service path for this extender.
it requires asmx method that not in the project.

Answer (score 2):

Your web service should be in the client tier - and this can call into your BL layer.

So what I mean is think of our web service is a client facing chunk of functionality. The web service itself should not really implement any logic - your Business logic layer should.

So in your web service you would have (in psuedocode)

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] AutoComplete(string input){
    return _businessLogic.AutoComplete(input);

}
```

Comment: Yes i did the same.getting the data from DL And logic is in bl and that method is exposed as webserice    .i refering those webserive in my website.Now the problem is AutoCompleteExtender requires asmx for service path and method name in that service. i have \App_WebReferences\Myservicename.discomap.

Comment: Sorry I am struggling to understand this. Could you please send a screenshot or something of what you have in your filesystem?

Comment: @rangitaanz let me help you .i have 5 project in my solution.1:interface                                                 2:BL         3:DL           4:Web services     5:Client Website    every BL exposed as webserive.which I using as reference in my website**client Website**...

Comment: Hi Madhav, structure sounds fine. So you have added a web service to your services layer? What type of project is that? Typically you will want to host your webservices in a web project - it has to be able to be connected to via the web after all. You can use WCF to have a service in another layer and use binding to wire it all up in the web.config - giving it a set url that you can connect to. But with the type of web service you are using the best is to have it in a web project. Does that make sense?